# Obfuscating a command within a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, command

There are a lot of tips (and warnings) on here for obfuscating various items within scripts.
I'm not trying to hide a password, I'm just wondering if I can obfuscate an actuall command within the script to defeat the casual user/grepper.
Background:  We have a piece of software that helps manage machines within the environment.  These machines are owned by the enterprise.  The users sometimes get it in their heads that this computer is theirs and they don't want "The Man" looking over their shoulders.

I've developed a little something that will check to see if a certain process is running, and if not, clone it up and replace.
Again, the purpose of this is not to defeat anyone other than the casual user.

It was suggested that one could echo an octal value (the 'obfuscated' command) and use it as a variable within the script.  e.g.:

```
strongBad=`echo "\0150\0157\0163\0164\0156\0141\0155\0145"`
```

I could then use $strongBad within the shell script to slyly call the commands that I wanted to call with arguments?

```
/bin/$strongBad -doThatThingYouDo -DoEEET
```

Is there any truth to this?  So far it's worked via command line directly into shell (using the -e flag with echo) but not so much within the script.  I'm getting unexpected output, perhaps the way I'm using it?

As a test, try this in the command line:

```
strongBad=`echo -e "\0167\0150\0157"`
```

And then

```
$strongBad
```

You should get the same output as "who".

EDIT

Upon further review, the addition of the path to the echo command in the variable is breaking it.  Perhaps that's the source of my issue.

Comment: `/usr/sbin//bin/echo`? I don't think so.

Comment: actually the variable contains the contents of the echo.. when called via the secondary command, it actually works.

Comment: Oh, that's backticks, not `'`

Comment: An easy google search gave me this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/shellcrypt/

Comment: Yes, I know how it works, I just didn't notice the backticks.

Comment: I was hoping to not have to install something else.. again, this doesn't have to be strong (or even weak).. it's strictly to defeat the casual person who thinks they know more than they actually know.

Comment: sorry, fixed bogus octal obfuscation.  I'm actually wondering if the problem is the addition of the path to the echo command in the variable.

Comment: Note that `/bin/echo` and `bash`'s built-in echo may treat `-e` in opposite ways.

Comment: Also, in `bash` you don't need `echo` at all: `strongBad=$'\150\157\163\164\156\141\155\145\015\012'`.

Comment: ooOOOoo! Let me try that!  Thanks!

Comment: Just write it in a compiled language (or quick&dirty perl), and give it innocent name and default output and functionality. Or piggyback some actual open source daemon or tool.

Comment: None of these techniques will obfuscate the name of the command in the process list, so it doesn't make much sense to me to worry about people doing `grep <command>` on your invocation script when they can much more easily just do `killall <command>`...

Comment: killall is fine, the process will resurrect itself.  This is really more for people who try to find anything on the system with the name "command_so_and_so" and want to delete it & everything associated with it.  Again, I'm not trying to be fool proof, I'm just trying to fool the fools.

The long and short of it, I don't want this script to be easily found.

Comment: Just look at the JavaScript malware spam in your inbox for significant additional inspiration.

Comment: Would you consider obfuscating the entire script ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a [rotate 13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) on any command you want hidden beforehand, then just have the the obfuscated command in the shell script.

This little bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function rot13 {
   echo "$@" | tr '[a-m][n-z][A-M][N-Z]' '[n-z][a-m][N-Z][A-M]'
}


rot13 echo hello, world!

`rot13 rpub uryyb, jbeyq!`
```

Produces:

```
rpub uryyb, jbeyq!
hello, world!
```

Comment: The only problems is this is OS X, so the number of useful tools like rot13 is limited.  :(

Comment: I am using a function. You don't need to have a seperate rot13 tool.